# In GCC, what are "tree optimizations" vs "RTL optimizations"?

Tags: gcc, compiler-optimization

When I file a bug against GCC about a missed optimization, I am always at a loss whether I should file it under "rtl-optimizations" or "tree-optimizations". I looked at the [components page](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/describecomponents.cgi?product=gcc) on the GCC bugzilla, and it isn't really explained there.

So, what are these two kinds of optimizations, or rather what distinguishes between them?

Comment: Note that when filing a bug, it doesn't matter if you get it wrong, someone else will fix it for you. Actually, there may not even be a "right" one, similar optimizations can be implemented in different ways in different places.

Answer (score 7):

Partial answer:

The distinction has to do with different internal representations of (semi-compiled) programs within the GCC compiler. This is actually a rather complex issue, but for the purposes of this question:

- There's a [abstact-syntax-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)-based representation called GIMPLE. Some optimization passes are made on this representation; see [this list](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Tree-SSA-passes.html#Tree-SSA-passes). These are known as **Tree Optimizations** or **Tree-SSA Optimizations**.
- A later and "lower-level" representation is in the [Register Transfer Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_transfer_language) (or RTL). Other optimization passes are made on this representation, later in the process than the tree optimizations; here's a [list of these](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/RTL-passes.html#RTL-passes). These are call **RTL optimizations**.

That being said, I haven't given an easy rule-of-thumb for distinguishing which optimizations belong where.

---

For a lot more information, you might want to read the [GCC internals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/index.html#Top) guide, where I've found the lists of optimization passes.